# Multipart/form-data requests in .NET 2.0

Tags: c#, rest, .net-2.0

I am trying to create a Multipart/form-data POST request in a .NET 2.0-project for a work assignment. However, from what I understand the MultipartFormDataContent Class wasn't introduced until .NET 4.5.

My question: is it possible and how would one create a Multipart/form-data POST request to a API in .NET 2.0? The request should contain a .zip-file sent as formData.

Comment: Hi there! Your question is too broad. Here, on stackoverflow, we dealing with coding issues, so if you have a problem with your code (exceptions, unpredictable behavior, etc.) - edit your question or ask another one. You may also find this link useful: [ask]

Comment: what is `3rd part API`?

Comment: @JohnB sorry, I edited the question now with correct information